# Get previously selected node before SelectedNodeChanged event is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, treeview, nodes

I need to get the previous selected node before this event is called

```
protected void treeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

From msdn, there are something called **newnode** and **oldnode** and it applies to **TreeViewSelectEventArgs** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529720(v=vs.85).aspx), but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using ViewState or depending on your requirement, you can use Session variable as well:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write("Previous Node ::: " + ViewState["PreviousNode"] + "<br/>");
     if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
     {
           Response.Write("Current Node :::" + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString());
     }
}

protected void treeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ViewState["PreviousNode"] = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString();

}
```

Comment: i understand by using viewstate, this can be achieved as well, but is there any built in features in treeview to achieve this as well?

Comment: I doubt there is any built in property to access previous active node.